# How to get another app's tile image in Windows 8 using WinJS?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I am trying to get the Tile/Icon image of another app, so I can use it in my application.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from your app code?  If so, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the only way to do this would be to contact the author of the app, and request their permission, and have them send you the tile image. There is no API in WinJS for interacting with the tiles of other applications.